# What's the probability of rolling 10 dice each with 10 sides and each will have to same number?

Tags: probability, dice

I think the probability is $1\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}\cdot{1\over 10}={1\over 10^9}={1\over 1,000,000,000}$ because I have ten dice and there are ten numbers that can be matched, so there has to be a one at the beginning of multiplying and all of the other possibilities that you will get won't have every number the same, so there should be $1\over 10$s for the next nine places in multiplying to then get the answer.  What do you think?  Am I right?  I think I am.  If not, what do you think the answer should be?

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: That's right! The first one can be anything the other 9 have 1/10. So your number.

Comment: You can write ${1\over10}\cdot{1\over 10}$ or ${1\over 10}\times{1\over10}$.  There's no need for uncouth notation like ${1\over10}*{1\over10}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: "Uncouth"?  Also, is there _anyone_ who can answer?

Comment: @VladInTheTaylor You have the answer, that you calculation and your thoughts are right. What´s your problem ?

Comment: I certainly have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is good enough.  If there are *only* the numbers 1-10, then rolling the same number on each die would be ten out of $10^{10}$, which is 10/10,000,000,000, which would be equal to 1/1,000,000,000.  It looks like I *do* have the answer!

Comment: Well, I _do_ know that I need to answer my own questions in first person.